# NSMutable Dictionary adding objects

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Is there a more efficient way to add objects to an NSMutable Dictionary than simple iteration?

Example:

```
// Create the dictionary

NSMutableDictionary *myMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    

// Add the entries

[myMutableDictionary setObject:@"Stack Overflow" forKey:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
[myMutableDictionary setObject:@"SlashDotOrg" forKey:@"http://www.slashdot.org"];
[myMutableDictionary setObject:@"Oracle" forKey:@"http://www.oracle.com"];
```

Just curious, I'm sure that this is the way it has to be done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have all the objects and keys beforehand you can initialize it using NSDictionary's:

```
dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:
```

Of course this will give you immutable dictionary not mutable. It depends on your usage which one you need, you can get a mutable copy from NSDictionary but it seems easier just to use your original code in that case:

```
NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWith....];
NSMutableDictionary * md = [dic mutableCopy];
... use md ...
[md release];
```

Comment: Thank you for the second opinion. I just wanted to be sure I was not missing anything and to see if there was something a bit more efficient / elegant.

Comment: I was as well searching for an option to initialize NSMutableDictionary with objects and keys like you can do for NSDictionary but I can't find anything ...

Answer (score 20):

```
NSDictionary *entry = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.x], @"x",
  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.y], @"y",
  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.z], @"z",
  [NSDate date], @"date", 
  nil];
```

Answer (score 8):

Allow me to add some information to people that are starting.

It is possible to create a `NSDictionary` with a more friendly syntax with [objective-c literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas):

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ 
    key1 : object1, 
    key2 : object2, 
    key3 : object3 };
```

Comment: should you end the list with a nil?

Comment: @vvMINOvv No need :). The same with NSArrays literals :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *example = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@5,@"burgers",@3, @"milkShakes",nil];
```

The objects come before the keys.