# NSArray NSDictionary NSNumber using @operator in Xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, xcode4.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apple LLVM 4.0 new features on Xcode 4.4 (Literals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/apple-llvm-4-0-new-features-on-xcode-4-4-literals)

I've read a this [article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011649-SW1).

i found great skills. is a about @operator.

> Literals syntax is supported for NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSNumber objects, using the same ‘@’ operator as for NSString literals.

but, i can't find any sample code.

could you please some more explain about NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary using the @operator?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out about the new syntax in LLVM's manual page about [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 1):

Mike ash wrote a very good [article](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html) on the topic:

It covers the basics, as well as some really cool implementation details.
This should at least get you started, if you have any other questions please leave a comment below!

Comment: I have not removed link just gave formatting and link was attached to article. or was removed ?

Comment: @Jennis ah, good point, sorry, I missed the fact that you inlined the link. SO's diffing leaves much to be desired, you were correct.

Answer (score 0):

The best docs I've seen so far are in the [llvm man page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

```
  // integral literals.
  NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;             // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]
  NSNumber *fortyTwoUnsigned = @42U;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:42U]
  NSNumber *fortyTwoLong = @42L;        // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLong:42L]
  NSNumber *fortyTwoLongLong = @42LL;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:42LL]

  // floating point literals.
  NSNumber *piFloat = @3.141592654F;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.141592654F]
  NSNumber *piDouble = @3.1415926535;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.1415926535]

  // BOOL literals.
  NSNumber *yesNumber = @YES;           // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
  NSNumber *noNumber = @NO;             // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]

  // This creates an NSArray with 3 elements. The comma-separated sub-expressions of an array
  // literal can be any Objective-C object pointer typed expression.
  NSArray *array = @[ @"Hello", NSApp, [NSNumber numberWithInt:42] ];

  // Immutable dictionary expression:
  NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"name" : NSUserName(),
    @"date" : [NSDate date],
    @"processInfo" : [NSProcessInfo processInfo]
  };
```