# What kind of object does @[obj1, obj2] create?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-literals

I came across the following:

```
NSArray *array = @[object1, object2];
```

It seems to be creating an `NSArray`, but is this array instance an autoreleased object, or must I release it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a new collection literal available in the compiler that ship with xcode 4.4 and above

```
@[object1, object2];
```

is equivalent to

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];
```

so yes, it is an autoreleased object, if you need this to be retained, you can do

```
myRetainedArray = [@[object1, object2] retain];
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/apple-llvm-4-0-new-features-on-xcode-4-4-literals) has a good description of all of the new literals

Comment: if I need to create a not autorelease object, can't use above literal?

Comment: you can still use it, just retain the array afterwards

Comment: Thanks wattson12. Is it also possible to intentionally release above autoreleased object?

Comment: this literal is just a convenience to make creating arrays neater. you still have to manage its memory the same as you would with any other object (or switch to ARC)

Comment: "is equivalent to" It's not equivalent. It uses `arrayWithObjects:count:` internally. `arrayWithObjects:` will stop at the first `nil` argument, which means if you have a `nil` value in the list, it will stop there, and there is no error; whereas with array literals (as well as `arrayWithObjects:count:`), it will throw an exception if one of the things in the list is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the new llvm compiler's literal for creating an array. The compiler changes this to:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: object1,object2,nil];
```

So it is returning an autoreleased object.

A Google search brought up further info:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: "The compiler changes this to:" No, it changes it to use `arrayWithObjects:count:`.