# Why object property auto released in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

example code:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *t

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.t = @{@"a": @"b", @"c": @"d"};
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)testMethod {
    //self.t is released! accessing self.t cause an SIGABRT
}
```

the question is: what's wrong with this code?

It works fine when I use "copy"

```
self.t = [@{@"a": @"b", @"c": @"d"} copy];
```

OR

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *t
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759708/what-kind-of-object-does-obj1-obj2-create

Comment: Your code should work fine (and does here) as it defaults to `strong`. Show how you instantiate the class and how you call `testMethod`.