# New syntax for arrays in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apple LLVM 4.0 new features on Xcode 4.4 (Literals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/apple-llvm-4-0-new-features-on-xcode-4-4-literals)

I am using Xcode 4.5 and would like to use the new syntax to adding objects to arrays, in my old code I have:

> NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: rabbit, chicken,
>   owl, nil];

What is the correct way to use the new syntax that is being introduced, for example:

> @[rabbit, chicken, owl]

TIA.

Comment: That is the correct way to create an NSArray using the object literal syntax. Was that your question?

Comment: Yes, I believe it was - I was just unsure the correct way to implement the @[... syntax! Seems very simple now!

Comment: Sometimes it's faster to just type your idea into your file and see if it compiles, than to ask about it on stackoverflow. ;^)

Comment: Please pick a correct answer to the thread :)

Comment: yes, it the correct way.

Comment: Just so you know, this syntax was introduced in 4.4, not 4.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, i.e.:

```
NSArray *array = @[ rabbit, chicken, owl ];
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have is correct.  Here is some more [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) on the subject.