# Objective-C literals for NSSet and NSOrderedSet?

Tags: literals, nsset, nsorderedset

What, if any, NSSet and NSOrderedSet operations can one perform with the new Objective-C collection literals?

For NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSNumber, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/apple-llvm-4-0-new-features-on-xcode-4-4-literals).

FWIW, [this Big Nerd Ranch Post](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/) says the indexing syntax is supposed to work for NSOrderedSet.  But in my tests it does not.  And I haven't been able to find anything about creating ordered sets.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no Objective-C literal syntax for NSSet. It doesn't really make sense to use index subscripting to access NSSet elements, although key-based subscripting might. Either by wrapping or subclassing, you *could* add your own.

(Correction):
Originally I had thought NSOrderedSet wasn't supported either, but it turns out that using index subscripting *is* supported, but there doesn't seem to be a way of initializing an NSOrderedSet with the literal syntax. However, you could use initWithArray: and pass a literal array:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet* oset = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray: 
    @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @42]];

oset[2] = @3;
NSLog(@"OrderedSet: %@", oset);
```

Outputs:

```
OrderedSet: {(
    a,
    b,
    3,
    d,
    42
)}
```

According to [this excellent post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html) by Mike Ash, you can add the methods that are used to support indexed subscripting to your own objects.

```
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)setObject: (id)obj atIndexedSubscript: (NSUInteger)index;
```

And similar methods for object-based keying:

```
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript: (id)key;
- (void)setObject: (id)obj forKeyedSubscript: (id)key;
```

Thus you could implement a wrapper (or with a bit more work, subclass it) around an NSSet and provide key-based retrieval. Cool!

Comment: From @Almo: `NSSet *aset = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @42]];`

Answer (score 43):

What about trying this, in case of NSSet:

```
#define $(...)  [NSSet setWithObjects:__VA_ARGS__, nil]
```

And using it like this:

```
NSSet *addresses = $(addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4);
```

;-)

Comment: I would prefer `[NSSet setWithArray:@[__VA_ARGS__]]` so that it will fail when there's a `nil` element instead of silently stopping early

Comment: Both this answer and the comment above are awesome. Be careful if Apple ever implements the $(...) literal format though.

Comment: To safeguard against future implementation of `$(...)` literal, just use: `#define set() [NSSet setWithArray:@[__VA_ARGS__]]`

Comment: #define macros can be hard bugs to find since there will be no symbols generated for the expression.