# expected ':' syntax error in my code

Tags: objective-c

My code is as follows:

```
NSString *str1 = @"Name";
NSString *str2 = @"Age";

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: str1, str2 count:2];
```

However when I Build & Run I get an exception thrown which says: Expected ':' right before the 'c' in `count`.

Why is this? I've tried inputting the ':' though I know that's syntactically incorrect and then Xcode asks me to close off with a ']' before `count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initWithObjects:count:` is for use with C arrays. In your case, you'll want to use `initWithObjects:` with a `nil` argument at the end:

```
NSString *str1 = @"Name";
NSString *str2 = @"Age";

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: str1, str2, nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just started learning Objective-C, just use the most convenient methods introduced recently:

```
NSArray* array= @[ str1, str2] ;
```

For more details, see [What are the details of "Objective-C Literals" mentioned in the Xcode 4.4 release notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas)

Comment: Yea I'm aware of this literal, however I want to understand the underlying mechanics of what I'm doing before I start shortcutting. Great suggestion though.

Comment: Great. Note that the literal is turned by the compiler into a call to `+[NSArray initWithObjects:count]` which you tried originally. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html