# What is @[] and @{} in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, equals, nsmutabledictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the details of “Objective-C Literals” mentioned in the Xcode 4.4 release notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas)

I've got question about `@[]` and `@{}`.

Some code taken from internet:

```
self.searches = [@[] mutableCopy]; 
self.searchResults = [@{} mutableCopy];
```

1. Is `@[]` equal to `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`?
2. Is `@{}` equal to `[NSMutableArray array]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No. `@[]` is equal to `[NSArray array]` or `[[NSArray alloc] init]`.
2. No. `@{}` is equal to `[NSDictionary dictionary]` or `[[NSDictionary alloc] init]`.

(depending on the context and whether you use [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) or not)

That's why you see things like `[@[] mutableCopy]` sometimes. This will create an empty immutable array and create a mutable copy of it.

The result is the same as using `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` or `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`.

Comment: yeah ... it's creating an autoreleased object so the answer is only correct when using arc.

Comment: I was assuming anyone starting with Objective-C at this time would use ARC, but good point.

Answer (score 1):

`@{}` is equal to `[NSDictionary dictionary]`

`@[]` is equal to `[NSArray array]`

so `[@[] mutableCopy]` creates an empty immutable object and then it makes a mutablecopy of it. I don't think you can do it less efficient.

Comment: yeah .. i copied it from the question ;)

Comment: There was a post somewhere about the performance of `mutableCopy` vs simple `alloc/init`, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 0):

First one **@[]** is a shorthand to create an Array, for example the following array of two elements:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"First", @"Second"];
```

Second one **@{}** creates a dictionary, for example:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"first" : someValue,
    @"second" : someValue,
};
```