# Issue implementing Glass Button UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, pointers, user-interface, uibutton

I'm a noob to iphone development and i'm having a weird issue while trying to implement Glass Buttons ([found here](https://github.com/hboon/GlassButtons)).  My build fails because I'm getting an "unexpected @ in program error" inside the MOGlassButtons.m file.  I haven't been able to find anything regarding how to resolve this issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MOGlassButton.m

```
self.gradientLayer1.colors = @[(id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(255, 255, 255, 0.45) CGColor], (id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(255, 235, 255, 0.1) CGColor]]; //<--"unexpected @ in program error" 

self.gradientLayer2.colors = @[(id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(205, 205, 205, 0) CGColor], (id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(235, 215, 215, 0.2) CGColor]]; //<--"unexpected @ in program error"
```

EDIT

```
#import "MOGlassButton.h"

// Courtesy of https://github.com/facebook/three20
#ifndef MO_RGBCOLOR
#define MO_RGBCOLOR(r,g,b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1]
#endif
#ifndef MO_RGBCOLOR1
#define MO_RGBCOLOR1(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:c/255.0 green:c/255.0 blue:c/255.0 alpha:1]
#endif
#ifndef MO_RGBACOLOR
#define MO_RGBACOLOR(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:a]
#endif
```

Comment: Could you please show us MO_RGBACOLOR? If it, as I suppose, a macro, chances are it is the culprit.

Comment: you can't just cast CGColorRef to id, why don't you just store UIColor

Comment: @xlc Can you expound on your comment?

Comment: `(id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(...) CGColor]` will cause run-time error, because `CGColorRef` is not `id`

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: I'm running Xcode 4.2

Comment: @xlc in my experience, this is no problem and I never had problems with this.
This seems logical to me, as NSMutableArray and CFMutableArrayRef are toll-free bridged and the latter obviously does allow CFType data structures like CGColor.

Comment: @JuliusMaximilianSteen ok, I never know `CGColorRef` can be stored in `NSArray`... there must be a reason that `UIColor` and `CGColor` are not toll-free bridged...

Comment: @JuliusMaximilianSteen do you know of any workaround?

Comment: @xlc Apple themselves do that in their documentation:
    `NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(id)    [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [colors addObject:(id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];`


See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

What do you mean by workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably the outdated version of Xcode you are running. Your code uses Objective-C literals (the `@[…]` part) which are supported since Xcode 4.4 and thus not valid in earlier releases. (see [What are the details of "Objective-C Literals" mentioned in the Xcode 4.4 release notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas))

Upgrading should fix your problem.

**Edit**

Alternatively, although I heavily recommend updating, you could use the following.

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(255, 255, 255, 0.45) CGColor], (id)[MO_RGBACOLOR(255, 235, 255, 0.1) CGColor], nil];
```