# How can I use an integer value as 'key' to set value in NSMutableDictionaryw with Ios

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

How can I use an integer value as 'key' to set a float value in NSMutableDictionary ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`NSNumber` literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas) you can do the following

```
[dict setObject:@5.562 forKey:@5];
//or
int key = 5;
float value = 5.562;
[dict setObject:@(value) forKey:@(key)];
```

And to retrieve:

```
float retrVal = [[dict objectForKey:@5] floatValue];
```

Comment: but how I could retrieve, if i doit like this?

Comment: The literals shouldn't be in parentheses. The parentheses are only used with variables.

Comment: @rmaddy `sed s/shouldn't/needn't/g`

Comment: if i write like this, i get this error `incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending int to parameter of type id`

Comment: Make sure you include the `@` and that you are using LLVM 4.0 or higher ( >= Xcode 4.4 ). If not then you will need to manually create [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s for the keys and values.

Comment: `for(id key in Data_of_Transaction1)
             {
                 NSDictionary* List_Bas = [Data_of_Transaction1 objectForKey:@(key)];
                 NSLog(@"%@",List_Bas);
             }`
not work :(

Comment: @user2299789 What kinds of objects are in `Data_of_Transaction1`? You probably just want `NSDictionary* List_Bas = [Data_of_Transaction1 objectForKey:key];` or `NSDictionary* List_Bas = Data_of_Transaction1[key];`

Comment: The `@` or `@()` syntax is used to wrap non-objects. In your loop, `key` is an object so you don't wrap the value.