# What is the easiest way to make a tree?

Tags: objective-c

I like doing game development and I've been doing some with Sprite Kit, but I keep getting stuck while trying to make tree structures. Things for data and configurations.

In javascript I would just make objects of objects of objects and do whatever I wanted. So something like:

```
[{
    location: {x: 2, y:12},
    allowedNodes: [2,5],
    someflag: true
  }, ...
];
```

Or make objects and reference them everywhere. I know there is a NSMutableDictionary and structs do exist, but ARC won't let you put any references in them.

I also come from a C++ background and I feel I can do anything at all in C++, but I'm having a really tough time with Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is the easiest way to build a tree. It's used in a wide range of cases, for example JSON data always get represented with `NSDictionary` objects. You can put any reference into the dictionary.

Regarding your example of a tree, it could be represented on Objective-C this way:

```
@[
    @{
        @"location": @{
            @"x": @2,
            @"y": 12
        },
        @"allowedNodes": @[
            @2,
            @5
        ],
        @"someflag": @YES
    }
];
```

Comment: Wow, considering the vagueness and angst in my question I'm surprised I got such a clear answer. The only thing I would add is how to access the values. Doing a search it sorta looked like you could do mydict[@0][@"location"][@"x"], but it does say it needs to be an objects, so @0 might not work.

Comment: `NSNumber *x = array[0][@"location"][@"x"];`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [Objective-C 2.0 literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas):

```
@{
    @"Key 1": @[@"Value 1", @"Value 2"],
    @"Key 2": @3,
    @"Key 3": @{@"Nested Key": @"Nested Value"}
}
```

These let you quickly create `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CFTree` in Core Foundation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFTreeRef/Reference/reference.html