# Using AFHTTPRequestOperation to construct URL (curly braces included)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I need to construct URL like this using `AFNetworking` the problem for me it's `{` and `}` how to pass throught `parameter`

```
/api/sth.json?filter[condition]={"53891":[123],"53892":[123,124]}
```

So my code looks like this (i made it simpler):

```
[self GET:myUrl parameters:@{
                             @"filter" : @{
                                     @"condition" : @{
                                             @"53891" : @[@(123)],
                                             @"53892" : @[@(123),@(124)]}
                                     },

                             } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                 success(operation,responseObject);
                             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                 failure(operation,error);
                             }];
```

But it's produce not expected output:

```
/api/sth.json?filter[condition][53891][]=123&filter[condition][53892][]=123&filter[condition][53892][]=124
```

There is a way to do this in `parameters` in `AFHTTPRequestOperation` or manually i have to put it into string?

**EDIT:**

My current solution is like that:

```
+(NSString*)convertFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dic {
    NSMutableString *outputStr = [NSMutableString new];
    [outputStr appendString:@"{"];
    NSArray *allKeys = [[dic allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO]]];
    for(NSString *key in allKeys) {
        NSArray *objects = dic[key];
        [outputStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\":[",key]];
        for(NSNumber *nb in objects) {
            [outputStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",[nb longValue]]];
            if(![nb isEqual:[objects lastObject]]) {
                [outputStr appendString:@","];
            } else {
                [outputStr appendString:@"]"];
            }
        }
        if(![key isEqual:[allKeys lastObject]]) {
            [outputStr appendString:@","];
        }
    }
    [outputStr appendString:@"}"];
    return outputStr;
}
```

Where input dictionary is:
`@{@"53892" : @[@(123),@(124)]}`

But it's nothing more than string compare. There is no more clever way to achieve it with AFNetworking directly since it's fairly standard URLs parameters?

Comment: Have you set `AFJSONParameterEncoding`  to your client with `setParameterEncoding` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 2 different ways of parsing a dictionary, and this cannot be done automatically. As Mehul said before, try serializing your parameter "condition" (converting its value to string) before creating the "parameters" dictionary:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"53891" : @[@(123)], @"53892" : @[@(123),@(124)]};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];

NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[self GET:myUrl parameters:@{
                                 @"filter" : @{
                                 @"condition" : params
                                 },

                         } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                             success(operation,responseObject);
                         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                             failure(operation,error);
                         }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

1. create dictionary
2. create json string from dictionary(first convert dictionary to `NSData` using `NSJsonSerialization` and then convert thata NSData object to NSString)
3. Now append this string in your URL in format which you want to attach to
4. create url from new string and pass it in get/post method with paramters dictionary as nil

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a numbers with parenthesis is for `expressions` :

```
@(6 + x * 2012)
```

Read excellent explanation post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349981/3096087

Maybe wrapping in parenthesis somehow messes up with AFHTTPRequestOperation.

`NSNumber` are directly declared the following way :

```
NSNumber *number = @123;
```

So try with an input dictionary the following way :

```
@{@"53892" : @[@123,@124]}
```